# MySQL select, concatenate with separator

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

My data looks like :

```
id   name   age   gender
1    abc          M
```

'age' value is null.

I want to concatenate column value with separator '\n' and if one column value is null, then also use '\n' to represent it.

I tried `concat_ws`, but it only return :

```
1\nabc\nM
```

**What I want is :**

```
1\nabc\n\nM
```

That is it should be 2 '\n' after 'abc'.

How can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use ifnull(column_name,'') to replace the null column with empty character and try concat_ws.

```
select concat_ws('\n',id,name,ifnull(age,''),gender) from table1;
```

SQL Fiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12074/10

Comment: because we don't know which column has null value, so we have to use 'ifnull' in each column in your solution such as 'select concat_ws('\n',id,ifnull(name,''),ifnull(age,''),ifnull(gender,'') from table1'.  Actually, our table has a great number of column, so there is a great number of 'ifnull' for each column.  This looks like complex and not clearly.  Do you have any better idea?

Comment: functions do not generally accept dynamic columns. In this case ifnull can only be applied to columns one by one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select concat_ws('\n', id, coalesce(name,''), coalesce(age,''), coalesce(gender,''))
from your_table
```

Comment: Doesn't that return `null` if `age` is `null`?

Comment: @juergen d, this works.  But actually we have a great number of column, so if we add 'coalesce' for each column, it seems that this sql statement is complex and not clear. Do you have better idea?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use concat_ws,It will not concat that value if it is null.use concat +ifnull function

```
select concat('\n', ifnull(id,''),ifnull(name,''),ifnull(age,''),ifnull(gender,'')) 
from your_table
```

Comment: use 'concat_ws' return '1\nabc\nM', but I want it return '1\nabc\n\nM'(there are 2 '\n' after 'abc').

Comment: then no need to use concat_ws use concat and isnull function.